# Installed windows 10 and Linux, how to safely remove the Lenovo recovery partitions without messing up the boot?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

Please look at the following screenshots.

1. Is /dev/sda1 useful at all (Windows says it is a Recovery Partition)? Can I remove it? It is only 1000MB and removing it seems no use, so the best I can do is just leave it?
2. /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6 are Recovery partition and OEM partition, and they occupy 14.4GB + 7GB in total, can I delete them? How shall I modify the boot so that deleting them won't mess up the boot (in /dev/sda2)?
3. Is it possible to move linux backward (to the current /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6) without affecting Linux data (and may be a little larger than current space)? What I wanted to do is to increase Windows 10 partition a bit by moving Linux backward.

The pictures are attached below.

Thanks.

[image: Partition View Under Linux]

[image: Partition View Under Windows]

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything, I suggest making an image of the entire disk.  That way you can recover if anything goes wrong.  Also, do it in steps.  That is, just do one step at a time, and boot both OS's in between steps so you can be sure nothing is broken.

sda5 and sda6 should be OK to remove.  I don't think you will need to make any modifications to the boot configurations.  After that, you can move sda7 and sda8 to the right.  That will take a significant amount of time, because it has to physically move all of the data.  Once that's done, extending sda4 should be a breeze.

I'm not well-versed in EFI, but I'm thinking you need to keep sda1.  I don't think Windows will be able to boot without it.  Even if I'm wrong about that, I don't think it's really worth the effort to try and recover that space.